# Firebase login not prompting

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to set up firebase simple auth.

according to the docs the following should prompt me to login. I have turned my popup blocker off and also tried wrapping it in a click event...but still no prompt. I am doing it locally, and have localhost permitted in firebases auth settings. Am I missing something, pretty much followed the getting started

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js'></script>
    <script>
    (function () {

        var chatRef = new Firebase('https://xxxx.firebaseio.com');
        var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {

        });

        auth.login('password', {
          email: '<email@domain.com>',
          password: '<password>'
        });

    }());
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a popup during login is to connect to a third party OAuth service like Facebook or Twitter (the login happens entirely on their site and returns a token to your page, thus the new window).

There is no popup window for email/password login since this is done entirely without a third party API. Since you haven't put anything in your simple login callback, there's really nothing to see. Try this instead:

```
var chatRef = new Firebase('https://xxxx.firebaseio.com');
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
   if( error ) { console.error(error); }
   else { console.log(user); }
});
```

Then open up your JavaScript console and see where it takes you!

Comment: Thanks Kato, I gave your code a try, simply getting null...also its on firebases simple email login page they mentioned the prompt :/ 

https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html

Right now I have no users set up could this be the issue..

Comment: Correct. It's null until you call auth.login(). That is odd regarding the prompt; looks like a doc bug. With email/pass, it would be your job to supply the prompt.